# making a function with typedef struct with arrays

Tags: c, arrays, typedef, structure

I was just wondering what I'm doing wrong here? The errors are mostly from my first function, am I calling it wrong?

```
typedef struct{ //typedef and function prototype
     int x, y, radius;
}circle;
int intersect(circle c1, circle c2);
```

part of the main function that I need for my function

```
circle c1 = {5, 6, 3.2};
circle c2 = {6, 8, 1.2};
```

returns 1 if its two circle arguments intersect. How do I call the arrays using struct properly? I keep getting errors

```
int intersect(circle c1, circle c2){

    float cx, cy, r, distance;
    cx = (circle c1[0].x - circle c2[0].x) * (circle c1[0].x - circle c2[0].x);
    cy = (circle c1[1].x - circle c2[1].x) * (circle c1[1].x - circle c2[1].x);
    r = (circle c1[2].x - circle c2[2].x);
    distance = sqrt(cx + cy);
    if (r <= distance){
        return 1;
    }else{
    return 0;
    }
}
```

I'm preparing for finals, so help will be appreciated

Comment: What is `circle c1[0].x` meaning to you?  It is not a valid *C* expression. And I don't understand why you are adding index operators like `[1]` or `[2]` ... Time to read a good C programming book.

Comment: Also, your radius field should be float given how you want to initialize your variables

Answer (score 2):

There are no arrays in your code, so don't try using array notation. Also, don't declare local variables that have the same names as the function parameters.

```
int intersect(circle c1, circle c2)
{
    float dx, dy, r, distance;
    dx = (c1.x - c2.x) * (c1.x - c2.x);
    dy = (c1.y - c2.y) * (c1.y - c2.y);  // x changed to y throughout
    r  = (c1.r + c2.r);                  // rewritten too
    distance = sqrt(cx + cy);
    if (r <= distance)
        return 1;
    else
        return 0;
}
```